# using Count on rows from third table in django

Tags: django

I have this models:

```
class MemberGroup(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Subgroup(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    member_group=models.ForeignKey(MemberGroup,related_name='membergroup_subgroup')

 class Members(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     subgroup=models.ForeignKey(Subgroup)
```

Now I want to count the number of members in a group but each member is part of a subgroup.

```
my_groups=MemberGroup.objects.all().values('id','name').annotate(c=Count('membergroup_subgroup'))
```

gives me number of subgroups in each group. But I want member instead and my attempts so far failed.

Comment: you dont have any relation with the Subgroup and Members model, without that how can you count the members belonging to a group

Comment: Oh man, sorry. I have it. I omitted here by mistake.

Comment: try this once my_groups=MemberGroup.objects.all().values('id','name').annotate(c=Count('membergroup_subgroup__members'))

Answer (score 0):

If you add a [ManyToMany Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to your `MemberGroup` in `models.py`:

```
class MemberGroup(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    members=models.ManyToManyField(Members)
```

then you can get the count like this:

```
 MemberGroup.objects.all().annotate(c=Count('membergroup_members'))
```

or for an individual group:

```
g = MemberGroup.objects.filter(...)
g[0].members.count()
```